# 12.04: Is it possible to close windows in "spread mode"?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, backport

I had to switch back to 12.04 after using 13.04 for a few weeks. I use the spread view (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>) in Unity a lot, and I liked the possibility of closing unused windows. If I understand correctly, Unity 7 will not be backported to 12.04.

Is there another possiblity to have this function, maybe using CCSM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 12.04 you can do this by *"enabling the plugin 'Scale Addons' in CCSM and enable the option to close windows on middle-click"*

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/876017/comments/38).

Before that you have to install CCSM and the compiz add-ons.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

If your launcher is on auto-hide, it may not appear after activating the function. Rebooting should solve this problem.

Comment: Thank your for the tip on the middle click. Do you know if there's a keyboard shortcut that does the same thing (closing windows from spread mode, without having to activate it)?

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio just Alt+F4 like always. You can chose the window using the arrow keys. I'm on 15.04 right now, though. But I can't imagine much has changed.

Comment: oh, yeah, that works on 14.04 too. I tried Ctrl+W, Ctrl+Q, but forgot about good old Alt+F4. I apologise for the brain fart. :p